# Finding a specified pattern in the data-- Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

My table has data as below

```
Column  
--------
1122 52
1122 62
1122 82
1122 12
112222 
1122442
```

I need to find the count of those numbers which has spaces in MIDDLE in a pattern Hive.

Please help me out in getting the count with explanation if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `like` and `count(*)`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where column like '% %';
```